# Can't set cursor position in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, cursor, uitextview

I'm working on an app that is highly dependent on UITextView. My ideal behavior is when a user quickly presses a double space, the text cursor will jump ahead 5 spaces to make space for a UIButton. I've implemented the following code, but the cursor doesn't seem to jump even though all the other actions in the "quickSpace" area happen. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: I think the problem is that I am trying to jump the cursor to a point outside of the range that currently exists. In other words, someone is entering new text into the UITextView and the range is set to wherever the cursor happens to be. Is that the end of the range? Is it possible to send a cursor outside of the range that currently exists?

```
    if(text==" "){  
        let now=Date()
        if let last=previousSpaceTimestamp
        {
            if now.timeIntervalSince(last)<0.3
            {
                //mainTextBox.text=textView.text.appending("hello")
                isQuickSpace=true
                var checkOffButton: UIButton=createCheckButton()
                checkOffButton.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
                checkOffButton.frame.size=CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
                //checkOffButton.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: CGFloat(buttonYPos))
               mainTextBox.addSubview(checkOffButton)
                buttonYPos=buttonYPos+15
                if let currentRange=mainTextBox.selectedTextRange
                {
                    if let newPosition=mainTextBox.position(from: currentRange.start,
offset: 200)
                    {
           mainTextBox.selectedTextRange=mainTextBox.textRange(from: newPosition,
to: newPosition)
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        }

        previousSpaceTimestamp=now

    }
    else
    {
            previousSpaceTimestamp=nil
     }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the TextView Range Like this in Main Queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        mainTextBox.isEditable = true
        mainTextBox.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 0)
    }
```

Comment: Where should that go?

Comment: Where add your button into TextView after that you need to put this code